# Create a graph with nodes as circles with texts

Tags: python, canvas, graph, networkx

Using Networkx,I'm creating a graph ,

I want to create each node as a circle and then define the edges.

```
    from tkinter import *
    import networkx as nx
    G=nx.Graph()
    G.add_node(0) # text say ,"Hello" placed in circle/rectangle
```

From the example given [here](http://www.ezgraphics.org/UserGuide/Text), I tried creating text label using canvas

```
Canvas.drawText(10, 20, "A Text String")
```

I get the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Canvas' has no attribute 'drawText'
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this or is there any alternative way of creating each node as a circle/rectangle containing text?

Comment: you have to initialize a canvas object first, you cant just access member functions without an instance, if you look a few pages back, you will see that they get a canvas object [here](http://www.ezgraphics.org/UserGuide/DrawingProperties)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to draw Networkx graphs is through it's [drawing](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html) API.

For example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(20, 2)
nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True, labels={node : 'some text {}'.format(node) for node in G.nodes()})
plt.show()
```

Will result in something like:
[image]